# Undefined index using more than one form

Tags: php

Here's my problem:
I have two forms on the same page.
The first form works fine.
But whenever I click the submit button on the second form, I get two notices.
The first says "undefined index: email" which is referring to "$email = $_POST["email"];" in my coding.
The second says "undefined index: password" which is referring to "$password = $_POST["password"];" in my coding.
I do not want my 2nd form to be affected by all the "if statements" I created for the first form.  And I'm going to be creating more "if statements" for the 2nd form soon.
For example, when I hit the submit button on the second form, it's echoing "You need to enter an email and password" which is an error I only wanted applied to the first form.

So MY QUESTION IS: How can I get the forms to only be affected by a specific group of "if statements"?  Like in css coding you apply ids, but what would i do to the forms or "if statements" so the "if statements" only affect specific forms?

Here's the coding:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
        <ul id="login">
            //login information
            <li id="loginn">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in">
            </li>
        </ul>
</form>

 <form action="" method="post"> 
        <ul id="register">
                     //register info list items
                             <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
            </li>
        </ul>
</form>

<?php

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if (empty($email) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = "You need to enter an email and password.";
} else if (user_exists($email) === false) {
    $errors[] = "The email you entered is not in our records. Have you registered?";
} else if (user_active($email) === false) {
    $errors[] = "Go to your email, open the email we sent you,and activate your account.";
} else {$login = login($email, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = "That email/password combination is incorrect.";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['users_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: homepage.php');
        exit();
    }
}

} 

if (empty($errors) === false) {

?>

<?php
echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `<hidden>` form field with the form's name:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="formname" value="form1">
```

Then, in the PHP, use that to discern the forms:

```
  if ($_POST['formname'] == "form1") {
      // ifs for first form
  }
```

(Note there is no error checking whatsoever in this code!)

Comment: Awesome I'll try this and let you know if it works for me!
Where exactly do I put the hidden form field though?

And I actually just started learning how to code a week ago so I don't know what you mean by error checking. Like are you talking about the functions the "if statements" are linked to?

Comment: The `<input type="hidden">` can go anywhere in the form. You won't see it. The error checking mainly refers to never to trust stuff from `$_POST`: http://johnbokma.com/websitedesign/forms.html

Comment: okay I did exactly as you said and now it's saying the formname inside "($_POST['formname']" is an undefined index.

Comment: @KacyRaye update your question so we can see what can be wrong.

Comment: I actually figured out how to do it.  
I added a name to the submit button and then created an if statement (similar to the one originally recommended) that engulfed all the other if statements.

Comment: The submit button method is another way of doing it yes. You could get some problems though when they have the same vlaue, or if you were to translate the page.